# Jquery is not call on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a jquery for file selection
http://jsfiddle.net/parvathy/e8wr5/

please look the fiddle. when i am clicking on the text box, that jquery is worked .. but when clicking on the "browse" button that is not worked.i am using boot strap css for button and input text please help me..

```
 <input type="text" name="fake_section" id="fake_section" class="form-control" style="float:left;">    
 <button type="button" id="fake_section" class="btn btn-primary" ">Browse</button>


$(document).ready(function () {
$('#fake_section').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#file').trigger('click');
});

$('#file').change(function (e) {
    var filename = $(this).val();
    var ext = filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['xls', 'xlsx']) == -1) {
        alert('Only add Excel Files!');
    }
    else {
        $('input[name="fake_section"]').val(filename);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: You have duplicate `id` attribute values. These need to be unique within the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have 2 elements with the id `fake_section`, use class instead - when you use an id selector it selects the first element with the given id

```
<input type="text" name="fake_section" class="fake_section form-control" style="float:left;">
<button type="button" class="fake_section btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:10px;">Browse-</button>
```

then

```
$('.fake_section').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#file').trigger('click');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6fwQp/)

Comment: but i want to use the boot strap class there

Comment: @Parvathiiiii you can have multiple classes for an element

Comment: Any Idea why I got the Bootstrap styling on your FIDDLE @ArunPJohny, and in Parvathiiiii's not?!?

Comment: @dollarvar I added those library references under the `External Resources` section in the left panel

Comment: Ui, nice new knowing about the features in JSFIDDLE, thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Be attention on the ids, your mistake were the same id in two controls. Some IDEs help you with a warning when you have many controls with the same Ids.

```
<input type="text" name="fake_section" id="fake_section2" class="form-control" style="float:left;">    
 <button type="button" id="fake_section1" class="btn btn-primary" ">Browse</button>


$(document).ready(function () {
$('#fake_section1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#file').trigger('click');
});
```